# J: Tacit adverb of Newton's method

Tags: operators, j, newtons-method, tacit-programming

I've found in `'addons/math/misc/brent.ijs'` implementation of Brent's method as an adverb. I would like to build a Newton's method as an adverb too but it's much harder than building tacit verbs.

Here is a explicit version of Newton's iteration:

```
   newton_i =: 1 : '] - u % u d.1'
```

With such usage:

```
   2&o. newton_i^:_ (1) NB. (-: 1p1) must be found
1.5708
   2 o. 1.5708 NB. after substitution we get almost 0
_3.67321e_6
```

And of course, for convenience:

```
    newton =: 1 : 'u newton_i^:_'
```

What's a tacit equivalent?

Comment: I think `d.` prevents you from writing a tacit adverb in this case.

Comment: The short answer is `n_i =: d.0 1 (%/@:) (-\`) (]\`) (\`:6)` and   `newton =: n_i (^:_)`. I'll come back and [explain why](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2010-November/021172.html) later (I'm on a phone right now).

Comment: @DanBron, Thank you very much! I've understood everything with help of your message link except why ``(-`) (]`) (`:6)`` not ``(]`) (-`) (`:6)`` for building `] - f` fork.

Comment: Danylo: because adverb trains are built up from left-to-right (i.e. LIFO); think of `f (d.0 1) (%/@:)` as a black-box that builds up (effectively) `(f % f d.1)`; well then you've got `black_box (\`-) (\`])`, which, read in *reverse* (LIFO), reads `]`,`-`,`black_box`, which then gets executed into the train `] - black_box`.  No, the real sneaky trick here was using `d.0 1` :) . Does that clear it up, or would you still like me to post a formal answer?

Comment: Dan, I've completely understood `f (d.0 1) (%/@:)` trick :) - it's cool indeed: we calculate zeroth and first derivatives of `f` and then insert `%` between them. I've understood the order in which you've written these three adverbs as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dan: Formally, I'd like to have an answer not in comments. If you post your short answer ``newton_i =: d.0 1 (%/@:) (-`) (]`) (`:6)`` I will accept it. Then I'll add the whole explanation as I've understood .

Comment: Cool, I'll do that then. After you've made your edits, I'll add or clarify anything as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

Per [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690417/j-tacit-adverb-of-newtons-method#comment42031688_26690417), a short answer; the tacit equivalent to the original, explicit `newton_i` and `newton` are, respectively:

```
n_i =: d.0 1 (%/@:) (]`-`) (`:6) 
newton =: n_i (^:_)
```

Some techniques for how such translations are obtained, in general, can be found on [the J Forums](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2010-November/021172.html).

### Construction

The key insights here are that (a) that a function is identical to its own "zeroeth derivative", and that (b) we can calculate the "zeroeth" and first derivative of a function in J simultaneously, thanks to the language's array-oriented nature. The rest is mere stamp-collecting.

In an ideal world, given a function `f`, we'd like to produce a verb train like `(] - f % f d. 1)`. The problem is that tacit adverbial programming in J constrains us to produce a verb which mentions the input function (`f`) once and only once.

So, instead, we use a sneaky trick: we calculate *two* derivatives of `f` at the same time: the "zeroth" derivative (which is an identity function) and the first derivative.

```
   load 'trig'
   sin              NB. Sine function (special case of the "circle functions", o.)
1&o.

   sin d. 1 f.      NB. First derivative of sine, sin'.
2&o.

   sin d. 0 f.      NB. "Zeroeth" derivative of sine, i.e. sine.
1&o."0

   sin d. 0 1 f.    NB.  Both, resulting in two outputs.
(1&o. , 2&o.)"0

   znfd =: d. 0 1   NB. Packaged up as a re-usable name.
   sin znfd f.
(1&o. , 2&o.)"0
```

Then we simply insert a division between them:

```
   dh =: znfd (%/@) NB. Quotient of first-derivative over 0th-derivattive

   sin dh
%/@(sin d.0 1)

   sin dh f.
%/@((1&o. , 2&o.)"0)

   sin dh 1p1  NB. 0
_1.22465e_16

   sin 1p1     NB. sin(pi) = 0
1.22465e_16
   sin d. 1 ] 1p1  NB. sin'(pi) = -1
_1
   sin dh 1p1  NB. sin(pi)/sin'(pi) = 0/-1 = 0
_1.22465e_16
```

The `(%/@)` comes to the right of the `znfd` because tacit adverbial programming in J is LIFO (i.e. left-to-right, where as "normal" J is right-to-left).

### Stamp collecting

As I said, the remaining code is mere stamp collecting, using the standard tools to construct a verb-train which subtracts this quotient from the original input:

```
   ssub  =: (]`-`) (`:6)     NB. x - f(x)

   +: ssub                   NB. x - double(x)
] - +:
   -: ssub                   NB. x - halve(x)
] - -:

   -: ssub 16                NB. 16 - halve(16)
8
   +: ssub 16                NB. 16 - double(16)
_16
   *: ssub 16                NB. 16 - square(16)
_240
   %: ssub 16                NB. 16 - sqrt(16)
12
```

Thus:

```
    n_i =: znfd ssub         NB. x - f'(x)/f(x)
```

And, finally, using ["apply until fixed point" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682404/j-why-does-fproposition-y-stand-for-a-while-loop/18685836#18685836) of `^:_`, we have:

```
    newton =: n_i (^:_)
```

Voila.

Comment: Very nice method and solution.

Comment: @DanBron, I have added to your answer my explanation as I've understood. Have you received it?

Comment: @Danylo, I did not, maybe it was rejected by other users before I was notified? Do you want to add an answer that I can copy-paste from?

Comment: @DanBron, no, I'm too lazy. Your explanation [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2010-November/021172.html) is great.

Comment: @DanBron, Recently I've found where is my rejected edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6149041. I wonder how people not competent in question do rating.

Comment: Also, note that this can quite easily extend to functions of more variables with: `n_i =: D.0 1 (%./@:) (]\`-\`) (\`:6)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 newton_i =: 1 : '] - u % u d.1'
```

is semi-tacit, in that a tacit verb results when it is bound with a verb (the adverb disappears when bound).

```
 newton_i2 =: 1 : '(] - u % u d.1) y'
```

is full-explicit in that binding with a verb does not resolve the adverb.

```
 + 1 : 'u/'
```

+/

```
 + 1 : 'u/ y'
```

+ (1 : 'u/ y')

There is no huge importance to making semi-tacit adverbs fully tacit, as there may be no performance gains, and it has the same benefit of being resolved within the adverbs locale rather than in callers (the case for fully explicit adverbs).